# Stored procedure parameter names in a PreparedStatement instead of parameter indexes?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Right now when I call a stored procedure in a `PreparedStatement` I have to add the parameters to the `CallableStatement` like so:

```java
procStmt.setString(1, "a");
procStmt.setString(2, "b");
procStmt.setString(3, "c");
// etc...
```

Which can get pretty tedious once you have about 50+ parameters in the stored procedure you're calling and not all of them are required. Is there a way to rather do it like this:

```java
procStmt.setString("myParameter", "a");
procStmt.setString("yourParameter", "b");
procStmt.setString("ourParameter", "c");
// etc...
```

This way the arguments gets passed directly to the parameters that require them and you don't have to worry about the order you send through the arguments or needing to send empty `String` objects etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you using PreparedStatement.. you can use CallableStatement to invoke a stored procedure and Callable Statement provides option to set values by parameter name...

Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Ah! I KNEW there was something like this! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

JDBC does not support named parameters. If you are using Spring I would suggest to use Spring JDBCTemplate [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html). It can be used without the whole IoC container.